# SQL query question of How can i remove duplicates regardless of the column order

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table called flight info.

```
departure   arrival
  A            B
  C            A
  A            C
  C            A
  B            C
  C            D
  D            B
  A            C
  B            A
```

The out put should be:

```
 departure    Arrival
  A             B
  A             C
  B             C
  C             D
  D             B
```

I try to use GROUP BY on both columns. However, I cannot find a way to identify same letters but in different order at two columns. Please help me out. Thank you so much and I appreciate it.
[I prefer MYSQL solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select distinct
    case when departure<=arrival then departure else arrival end as X,
    case when departure> arrival then departure else arrival end as Y
from T
```

Comment: by adding END then it works. This answer generates correct result. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Ok, forgot the END.  Try that.  Also, it's more of a hint than a solution!

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select distinct arrival, departure
from t
where arrival < departure or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.arrival = t.departure and t2.departure = t.arrival
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9a28f393150721cde3682124e25eccb) is a db<>fiddle

The first condition selects all rows where the arrival is smaller than the departure.  The second adds in the pairs where the inverse is not in the table.

Comment: Wizard points fir understanding the question man, I am still struggling

Comment: @TomLin . . . Your data has duplicate rows, so a `select distinct` is a simple fix.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query
First I concat both column with condition

```
SELECT   departure,arrival, 
CASE WHEN departure>arrival THEN CONCAT(arrival,departure) ELSE CONCAT(departure,arrival) END c
FROM t1
ORDER BY c
```

then select the first column if data has A,B and B,A. This will select A,B and next row return null. Like ranking

```
SELECT departure,arrival,@winrank := IF( @cvalue=NULL ,c, IF(@cvalue=c,NULL,c)) AS r ,
@cvalue :=c AS r1
FROM (
SELECT   departure,arrival, 
CASE WHEN departure>arrival THEN CONCAT(arrival,departure) ELSE CONCAT(departure,arrival) END c
FROM t1
ORDER BY c) t , (SELECT @cvalue :=NULL) r
```

And the final query is

```
SELECT departure,arrival FROM (
SELECT departure,arrival,@winrank := IF( @cvalue=NULL ,c, IF(@cvalue=c,NULL,c)) AS r ,
@cvalue :=c AS r1
FROM (
SELECT   departure,arrival, 
CASE WHEN departure>arrival THEN CONCAT(arrival,departure) ELSE CONCAT(departure,arrival) END c
FROM t1
ORDER BY c) t , (SELECT @cvalue :=NULL) r) f
WHERE f.r IS NOT null
```